# Question about indent lengths in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, tocloft

It seems that there is a different length between the different levels. It seems it is larger between the `subsection` and `subsubsection` as opposed to between the `section` and `subsection`. I have read that using the `tocloft` package that  `indent` and `numwidth` control these lengths. How do I change them so they are all 0.5 in? and also include down to the paragraph level? (just a note: I don't want to change the indenting size in the body just the ToC)

Answer (score 28):

The following table (taken from the `tocloft` documentation) lists the standard values for the `indent` and `numwidth`:

[image]

You can use `\cftsetindents` to control the `indent` and `numwidth` values for the entries; the syntax is

```
\cftsetindents{<entry>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}
```

To include the paragraphs, you will have to change the counters `tocdepth` (controlling the level up to which entries will appear in the ToC) and `secnumdepth` (controlling the level up to which sectional units will be numbered). A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\cftsetindents{section}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{paragraph}{0.5in}{0.5in}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]